# How to crop an image to a shape for eg. circle using Pillow in Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py, image-manipulation

How can I crop an image to a shape for eg. circle using Pillow in Discord.py?

My current code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member : discord.Member):
    welcome = Image.open('Welcome.jpg')
    
    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)
    pfp = pfp.resize((500, 500))
    welcome.paste(pfp, (657, 257))
    welcome.save("profile.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

- Open the pfp image as numpy array, convert to RGB

```py
img = Image.open(data).convert("RGB")
npImage = np.array(img)
h,w = img.size
```

- Create same size alpha layer with circle

```py
alpha = Image.new('L', img.size,0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)
```

- Convert alpha Image to numpy array

```py
npAlpha=np.array(alpha)
```

- Add alpha layer to RGB

```py
npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))
```

- Save the image with alpha!

```py
Image.fromarray(npImage).save('result.png')
```

### Example

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member : discord.Member):
    welcome = Image.open('Welcome.jpg')
    
    asset = member.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    img=Image.open(data).convert("RGB")
    npImage=np.array(img)
    h,w=img.size
    
    alpha = Image.new('L', img.size,0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
    draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)
    npAlpha=np.array(alpha)
    npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))
    pfp = Image.fromarray(npImage)
    welcome.paste(pfp, (657, 257))
    welcome.save("profile.jpg")
```

Comment: well I understood @Cloud

Comment: Great! Others who have the same question might benefit from an explanation though.

Comment: @SachinRaja added explanations for steps! thanks for pointing out :)