# discord.py Changing file size to add custom emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: I have an `on_message` event for a 'global chat' command that I have created. This would send messages to any server that was in the json, currently supporting images, multiple lines of text, and custom emojis (as long as the bot shared a server with said emoji).

[image: The on_message event]

**My problem**: As you can see in the image above, one person, 'S o u p', has their profile picture replaced with a duck emoji. For context's sake, their avatar is not that of a duck emoji. However, if you were to look at the most recent message, the profile picture is shown. I believe that the problem lies in the size of the `message.author`'s avatar. The PIL library may be a good solution, but I **do not** want to save the image.

**Code I have tried**:

```py
avatar_bytes = await message.author.avatar_url.read()
guildem = client.get_guild(738285544911405107)
    try:
        em = await guildem.create_custom_emoji(name=f'{message.author.name}', image=avatar_bytes)
    except:
        em = ''
```

The code above is the one I had used in the image example I had provided.

```py
avatar = message.author.avatar_url_as(size=128) # resize avatar
avatar_bytes = await avatar.read() # then read as bytes?
```

Above code gives exact same results. Avatars are turned into duck emojis.

**Others I have looked at**:

1. [How to crop an image to a shape for eg. circle using Pillow in Discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967507/how-to-crop-an-image-to-a-shape-for-eg-circle-using-pillow-in-discord-py): Messages did not send when using the code here. I assumed that using the PIL library would help reduce the file size significantly one way or the other without saving the image.
2. [How to reduce the image file size using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil): All the answers required saving the image, which I do not want to do. I tried tweaking the code a little bit, but caused all avatars to be turned into duck emojis.

If necessary, I will include the entire `on_message` event. However, this does not feel relevant nor necessary to include since the emojis are only a small portion of said event.

Edit: Here is the code to the entire `on_message` event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: # stop bot from replying to self
        return
    else:
        if not message.guild: # prevent errors when messaging in bot dm's
            return
        f = open("global text.json") # existing json
"""
{
    "747061937673732097": 765059798131539988,
    "724783642546536458": 818707151122989119,
    "761524419003809832": 813963773295591485,
    "755309786232258630": 760381389685784587,
    "738285544911405107": 738285544911405110
}
"""
        data = json.load(f)
        for i in data:
            if str(i) == str(message.guild.id):
                if data[str(message.guild.id)] == message.channel.id:
                    avatar_bytes = await message.author.avatar_url.read()

                    guildem = client.get_guild(738285544911405107) # guild to upload emojis to
                    try:
                        em = await guildem.create_custom_emoji(name=f'{message.author.name}', image=avatar_bytes) # create emoji using avatar_bytes in guildem server
                    except:
                        em = ''

                    ### functions ###
                    def censor(text): # censor words for safety
                        banned = ["test"] # bad words were here, removed for stackoverflow reasons

                        text = text.split()

                        nearly = []
                        for word in text:
                            if any(item in word.lower() for item in banned):
                                word = word.lower()
                                replaced = word.replace(word, ('#'*(len(word))))
                                nearly.append(replaced)
                            else:
                                nearly.append(word)

                        message = ' '.join(nearly)

                        return message

                    def parag(string): # check for \n
                        length = [string]
                        if string in ["", " ", "  ", "   "]:
                            return "<:transparent:774136812813811713>"
                        final_list = []
                        if '\n' in string:
                            length = string.split('\n')
                        for item in length:
                            thing = censor(item)
                            final_list.append(thing)
                        return paragger(final_list)

                    def paragger(list: list): # returns original message with \n
                        message = ""
                        for item in list:
                            message += f"> {item}\n"
                        return message

                    msg = parag(message.content)

                    ### attachment handling ###
                    embed_list = []
                    if message.attachments:
                        if len(message.attachments) == 1:
                            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.author}'s file", color=0xc39ce6)
                            for file in message.attachments:
                                embed.set_image(url=file.url)
                            embed_list.append(embed)
                        else:
                            count = 1
                            for file in message.attachments:
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.author}'s file {count}")
                                embed.set_image(url=file.url)
                                embed_list.append(embed)
                    
                    for i in data:
                        if str(i) != str(message.guild.id):
                            channel = client.get_channel(data[str(i)])
                            try:
                                await channel.send(f"{em} {message.author} \n{msg}", allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
                                if len(embed_list) > 0:
                                    for embed in embed_list:
                                        await channel.send(embed=embed)
                            except:
                                await channel.send(f"{em} {message.author} \n> {em}", allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions) # only happens if message is larger than 2000 char
                    if em != '':
                        await em.delete() # delete the custom emoji to make space for more emojis later on
                    break
    
    await client.process_commands(message) # process, prevent commands breaking
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: The `on_message` event code has been edited in, including comments for reading sake

Comment: You want to create a cutsom emoji from a profile picture, is that right?  Do you know that you wan create a webhook, and then send a message with the user name and the user profile picture like [this](https://i.imgur.com/xPQhooP.png)?

Comment: I know I can do this, but I would still want to use the emoji way. I think my question is mostly 'how do I make an image small enough to be an emoji without saving it' now that I think about it.

Comment: Perhaps try `avatar_bytes = io.BytesIO(await avatar.read())` instead of the line you have. (be sure to `import io`)

Comment: This brings up an attribute error, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`, the line of error being what you wrote (except `avatar` was replaced with `message.author.avatar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:
`em = await guildem.create_custom_emoji(name=f'{message.author.name}', image=avatar_bytes)`

You see, `discord.py` is looking for an emoji name with alphanumeric characters or underscores. `S o a p` does not fit this requirement, hence the error you have gotten. The following fixes the issue by replacing said characters with an underscore.

```py
avatar_bytes = await message.author.avatar_url_as(size=128).read() # size=128 makes the size smaller for emojis
name = message.author.name.replace('-', '_').replace(' ', '_') # Replace the erroring characters
try:
    em = await guildem.create_custom_emoji(name=f'{name}', image=avatar_bytes)
except:
    em = ''
```

EDIT: After taking another look, the problem wasn't what I thought after all, the issue with the user named S o a p was that it had non alphanumeric characters, I've updated my answer to fix this.

Comment: After implementing your code, there are still some avatars that will end up being returned as ''. I used the bot Carl-bot to test this since this bot's avatar wasn't able to show up in the first place.

Comment: @Bagle Try doing `except Exception as e` and then doing `print('Error: {e}'.format(e=e))` which should show what exception is given. Additionally, you might need to compress the image if the users' PFP is too large.

Comment: I've improved my answer with an edit by using the url_as function, since this will size it down for emoji purposes.

Comment: Using your new code, `url_as` function, the previously named bot Carl-bot's avatar is still not shown. The Exception is as follows: `400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: String value did not match validation regex.`
|| Tried again, replacing `image=avatar_bytes` with `avatar`, error: `'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: From the upload emoji page: “Must be alphanumeric or contains underscores”. Carl-bot’s name violates this rule. Try doing “name = message.author.name.replace(“-“,”_”)” then use name instead of message.author.name

Comment: @Bagle I've updated my answer to fix the original problem. The BytesIO stuff isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to save image. This is how you send images to discord without saving it:

```
import io
import PIL

image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), (255, 255, 255))
bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bytes_io, format="png")
bytes_io.seek(0)
file = discord.File(bytes_io, "white.png")
#now you can send this file to discord
await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Comment: But isn't this saving the image? Anyway, I'm converting the message author's profile picture into an emoji, so it would be originally in bytes rather than png as far as I can tell.